# Deleting an array element of a react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, react-state

I know this is not react problem and I suck at coding. Can somebody tell me why my code is running so strange!

my project is a simple Todo List. I have 3 components.

1. Main app component
2. TodoList component
3. TodoItem component

I want to delete a TodoItem when the user clicks the delete icon.

**this is app.js**:

```
const [todoLists, setTodoLists] = useState([]);

function setTodoList(index, setFunction) {
    setTodoLists(prevTodoLists => {
        const newTodoLists = [...prevTodoLists]
        newTodoLists[index] = {...setFunction(newTodoLists[index])};
        console.log([...newTodoLists])
        return [...newTodoLists];
    });
}

return (
    <section className="todoContainer" id="todocontainer">
        {
            todoLists.map((todoList, index) => {
                return <TodoList todoList={todoList} index={index} setTodoList={setTodoList} />;
            })
        }
    </section>
);
```

**This is TodoList.js**

```
function handleDeleteTodo(cardIndex) {
    setTodoList(index, prevTodoList => {
        const newTodoList = {...prevTodoList};
        newTodoList.cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
        return {...newTodoList};
    });
}
return (
    <section className="body" ref={todosBodyRef} >
        {
            todoList.cards.map((todo, cardIndex) => {
                return <TodoItem listIndex={index} cardIndex={cardIndex} todo={todo} handleDeleteTodo={handleDeleteTodo} />
            })
        }
    </section>
);
```

**This is TodoItem.js**

```
function deleteButtonOnClick() {
    handleDeleteTodo(cardIndex);
}
return (
    <>
        <p>{todo.name}</p>
        <div className="controls">
            <i className="far fa-trash-alt deleteCard" onClick={deleteButtonOnClick}></i>
        </div>
    </>
)
```

And when I Click On Delete Icon if TodoItem is the last TodoItem it deletes perfectly but if it's not the last item it will delete the next 2 Todoitems instead of itself.

I don't know what I did wrong. It will be great if someone explains to me what is happening :_(

**Edit:**
I added this if statement at `handleDeleteTodo`:

```
if (newTodoList.cards == prevTodoList.cards) {
    console.log("True"); // It means both cards references are Same.
}
```

And it logged True. This means both cards references are same and I have to clone that as well.

Is there anyways to solve this problem without cloning `cards` Array? Because I am cloning whole `todoList` Object and I don't want to clone cards too.

Comment: https://medium.com/@deniscangemi/remove-element-from-array-in-javascript-bf2d2428733#:~:text=Using%20Splice%20to%20Remove%20Array,number%20of%20elements%20to%20remove.

Comment: Why do you pass `index` (what is it anyway) instead of the `cardInex` in `TodoList`'s `setTodoList`'s invocation?

Comment: How do you pass the *cardIndex* to the  **handleDeleteTodo**? If you're passing the correct index value, then try to use  [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Comment: @k-wasilewski `todoLists` is an array of `todoList` that is an object that contains a `name` and `cards`. `cards` is an array of cards.

In order to modify a todoList I have to access it by it's index not the index of a card

Comment: @Miraziz `index` is the current TodoList array index.
I pass it as a prop from `App.js` to `TodoList.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

I was using a nested JS object and I was cloning it using spread operator. ( That is a shallow copy and it will not clone objects inside of objects! )

So I used [rfdc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfdc) and deep cloned my object using it. like this in **TodoList.js**:

```
import clone from 'rfdc/default';
function handleDeleteTodo(cardIndex) {
    setTodoList(index, prevTodoList => {
        const newTodoList = clone(prevTodoList); // This is where cloning happens
        newTodoList.cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
        return newTodoList;
    });
}
```